# Retrieving elements from array regarding to an accumulating parameter

Tags: algorithm

Assume that there are 2 arrays of elements and a function call will return elements within them. Each time a retrieval is performed, 8 elements will be retrieved from array 1, while 2 will be retrieved from array 2. And the elements to be retrieved is indicated by a number provided, assume that list 1 has 35 elements, and list 2 has 7, the situation will be like:

```
Assume the 2 arrays are:

array 1: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 35
array 2: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

number provided      elements from array 1              elements from array 2
1                    0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7      0, 1
11                   8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15     2, 3
21                   16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23     4, 5
31                   24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31     6
40                   32, 33, 34, 35                     0, 1
46                   0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7      2, 3
56                   8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15     4, 5
66                   16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23     6
75                   24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31     0, 1
85                   32, 33, 34, 35                     2, 3
...
```

Each time a retrieval is done, the count of numbers returned will be added to the last provided number become the next provided number. If one of the list is exhausted (remaining elements fewer than 8), then the remaining numbers will be retrieved from that list, and next time it will start retrieving elements start from index 0 again, like the situations when number 31 and 40 is passed.

The question is, is there anyway to determine what position to start in both array when a number is provided? e.g. when number 40 is given, I should start at 32 in list 1, and 0 in list 2. Like the above situation, list one is exhausted every 5th retrieval, while list 2 exhausted at every 4th retrieval, but since the provided number is based on the accumulated count of number retrieved, how can I determine where to start this time when a number is given?

I have been thinking this for days and really feel frustrated about it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Their is a cycle. And one cycle will have `total_num` numbers, we can get `total_num` from the code bellow:

`def get_one_cycle_numbers:
    n = len(a) / 8
    m = len(b) / 2
    g = gcd(n, m)
    total_num = len(a) * n / g + len(b) * m / g
    return total_num`

When we get the provided number `num` we just `num = num % total_num` and simulate the cycle.
PS: Hope I got the right understanding of the question.